# Adding in points based on description no GPS data using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, point, gps, import

I am working on a project that has a mix of points where half have specific GPS data and the other half only have descriptions of where the points are. I have added in and moved the GPS points to the correct places, but is there a way that I can add in points that don't have any location data and move them to the correct spots manually?

This is data on where window kill birds are found on my campus and only some were recorded with GPS locations, the rest are just descriptions. And I am doing this on ArcGIS Pro 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to proceed further, if you are well versed with your campus and if the number of records with just the description is less, you can manually create points at the desired location. The second approach could be geocoding these descriptions if you can modify the description to the exact address of the points.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/data/geocoding/convert-a-table-to-locations-on-the-map.htm